# add multiple buttons dynamically inside Grid-view

Tags: android, gridview

Can any one tell me the approach to set number of buttons dynamically in `Grid-View` items.I mean,Suppose i am having the `grid-view`(consist of categories of different products) of 3X3 and when i click on its first item i get the list of buttons of its sub-product inside grid-view first time and number differs for every item based on the availability of sub-products.

The list of buttons shown inside grid-view item may differ for every item click.I am new to android so any help will be appreciated

Here is my xml of adapter :-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <com.mss.skyjack.custom.views.SkyjackCustomTextview
                android:id="@+id/tv_product"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:drawablePadding="5dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/product"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textColor="@color/black_color" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/img_product"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />



                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/lnr_test"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:visibility="gone">
                </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:background="#000000" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <View
        android:id="@+id/view_right_line"
        android:layout_width="3dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#000000" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Here is my adapter class :-

```
public class ProductSelectorAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    Activity activity;
    List<SelectorTest> listSelector;
    private Button btn;
    List<catagoriesListModal> _categories;

    public ProductSelectorAdapter(Activity activity,
            List<SelectorTest> listSelector) {
        this.activity = activity;
        this.listSelector = listSelector;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return listSelector.size();
    }

    @Override
    public SelectorTest getItem(int position) {
        return listSelector.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        final ViewHolder viewHolder;
        _categories = listSelector.get(position).getCategories();
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.selector_items, parent,
                    false);
            viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
            viewHolder.tvProductName = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.tv_product);
            viewHolder.imgView = (ImageView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.img_product);
            viewHolder.viewRightLine = (View) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.view_right_line);
            viewHolder.lnrLayout = (LinearLayout) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.lnr_test);

            convertView.setTag(viewHolder);

        } else {
            viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }
        if (!activity.getResources().getBoolean(R.bool.landscape_only)) {
            if (position % 2 != 0) {
                viewHolder.viewRightLine.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            } else {
                viewHolder.viewRightLine.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        } else {
            if (position % 3 != 0 & position % 3 != 1) {
                viewHolder.viewRightLine.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            } else {
                viewHolder.viewRightLine.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        }

        SelectorTest selectorTest = listSelector.get(position);
        viewHolder.tvProductName.setText(selectorTest.getName());
        viewHolder.imgView.setImageResource(selectorTest.getImage());
        viewHolder.imgView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (activity.getResources().getBoolean(R.bool.landscape_only)) {
                    viewHolder.lnrLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    viewHolder.imgView.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                    for (int i = 0; i < _categories.size(); i++) {

                        btn = new Button(activity);
                        btn.setText(_categories.get(i).getName());

                        viewHolder.lnrLayout.addView(btn);
                        int idx = viewHolder.lnrLayout.indexOfChild(btn);
                        btn.setTag(Integer.toString(idx));

                        btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View v) {
                                String idxStr = (String) v.getTag();
                                Toast.makeText(activity, idxStr,
                                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                            }
                        });
                    }
                } else {
                    Session.ChangeFragmentWithBack(new ProductDetailFragment(),
                            "ProductDetailFragment", "ProductDetailFragment", 0);
                }

            }
        });

        return convertView;
    }

    static class ViewHolder {
        TextView tvProductName, tvTest;
        ImageView imgView;
        View viewRightLine;
        ListView lstroduct;
        ScrollView scrlLstItems;
        LinearLayout lnrLayout;
        Button btn1, btn2, btn3;
    }
```

Here is my SelectorTest model class :-

```
import java.util.List;

public class SelectorTest {
    int id;
    String name;
    int image;
    List<catagoriesListModal> categories;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getImage() {
        return image;
    }

    public void setImage(int image) {
        this.image = image;
    }

    public List<catagoriesListModal> getCategories() {
        return categories;
    }

    public void setCategories(List<catagoriesListModal> categories) {
        this.categories = categories;
    }

}
```

Here is my catagoriesListModal class :-

```
public class catagoriesListModal {
    String name;
    int id;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

}
```

Thanks

Comment: you must be using using an adapter for you grid view right? can you post the code for that.

Comment: Hey hars , thanks for your reply please check my updated post

Comment: What is it that you are getting after running the code that you pasted? Any error? Crash? or something else?

Comment: No i am not getting any crash but my view is getting overlapped and i am not sure that how can i shown different number of buttons in each grid-Item.

Answer (score 1):

Your approach is correct but your model doesn't take into account the categories in itself.
Modify your Model to Below.

```
import java.util.List;


public class SelectorTest {
int id;
String name;
int image;
List<String> categories;


public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}



public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public int getImage() {
    return image;
}

public void setImage(int image) {
    this.image = image;
}

public List<String> getCategories() {
    return categories;
}

public void setCategories(List<String> categories) {
    this.categories = categories;
}
}
```

Now modify your adapter Class accordingly

```
public class ProductSelectorAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

Activity activity;
List<SelectorTest> listSelector;
private Button btn;

public ProductSelectorAdapter(Activity activity,
                              List<SelectorTest> listSelector) {
    this.activity = activity;
    this.listSelector = listSelector;

}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return listSelector.size();
}

@Override
public SelectorTest getItem(int position) {
    return listSelector.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    final ViewHolder viewHolder;
    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.selector_items, parent,
                false);
        viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
        viewHolder.tvProductName = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.tv_product);
        viewHolder.imgView = (ImageView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.img_product);
        viewHolder.viewRightLine = (View) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.view_right_line);
        viewHolder.lnrLayout = (LinearLayout) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.lnr_test);

        convertView.setTag(viewHolder);

    } else {
        viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }
    if (!activity.getResources().getBoolean(R.bool.landscape_only)) {
        if (position % 2 != 0) {
            viewHolder.viewRightLine.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        } else {
            viewHolder.viewRightLine.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    } else {
        if (position % 3 != 0 & position % 3 != 1) {
            viewHolder.viewRightLine.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        } else {
            viewHolder.viewRightLine.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    }

    SelectorTest selectorTest = listSelector.get(position);
    viewHolder.tvProductName.setText(selectorTest.getName());
    viewHolder.imgView.setImageResource(selectorTest.getImage());


    convertView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (activity.getResources().getBoolean(R.bool.landscape_only)) {

                viewHolder.lnrLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                viewHolder.imgView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                List<String> _categories = listSelector.get(position).getCategories();
                for (int i = 0; i < _categories.size(); i++) {

                    btn = new Button(activity);
                    btn.setText(_categories.get(i));
                    viewHolder.lnrLayout.addView(btn);
                    int idx = viewHolder.lnrLayout.indexOfChild(btn);
                    btn.setTag(Integer.toString(idx));
                }
                btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        String idxStr = (String) v.getTag();
                        Toast.makeText(activity, idxStr, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    }
                });

            }
        }
    });

    return convertView;
}

static class ViewHolder {
    TextView tvProductName, tvTest;
    ImageView imgView;
    View viewRightLine;
    ListView lstroduct;
    ScrollView scrlLstItems;
    LinearLayout lnrLayout;

}
}
```

You must see that i have changed the variable position to final.(Just for a faster response) if you do not want to that.
you can create a custom View.OnclickListener which takes position as a parameter. something like this

```
class MyOwnClickListener implements OnClickListener {
    int position;

    public MyOwnClickListener(int position) {
        this.position = position;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
....
```

and for your convertView you can then use

```
convertView.setOnClickListener(new MyOwnClickListener(position) {
```

If any doubts do reach out.
Thanks

Update

```
  <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/scrollView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
     android:fillViewport="true" > 
    <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/lnr_test"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
                android:orientation="vertical"                        android:visibility="gone">
            </LinearLayout>
   </ScrollView>
```

Comment: I probably think you would be getting the list of your models over the network hence you would have to include those categories inside your response data

Comment: Hey hars Thanks for you idea ...and yes its working but i am still getting same problem that my dynamically created buttons are getting overlapped with my grid items can you please suggest a way to me so that i can handle this issue..

Comment: move your android:id="@+id/lnr_test" Linear Layout Inside a ScrollView. find the update. let me know if this works or not.

Comment: Hey ,Hars i had already tried this thing ...its was giving me same response my buttons are getting overlapped with my grid item.